# MFC Current class as argument

Tags: mfc, this, argument-passing

I have created the following MFC program :

CMyClass is the class, it has one CString member called "m" and one method called "MyFunc". I would like to pass the current class as argument for my method.

In the header file:

```
public:
   CString m;
   void MyFunc(CMyClass CM)
```

In the cpp file:

```
//Button event
void CMyClass::OnBnClicked()
{
   m = _T("");
   MyFunc(this);
   //MessageBox displaying the updated "m" member
   MessageBox(m,_T(""),MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

//Method updating the member m
void MyFunc(CMyClass CM)
{
   CM.m = _T("TEST");
}
```

The button click function updates the member "m" of the class and display the new "m" value but it does not change.
I would like to know why the argument "this" has not been properly passed. Is something wrong with my code ?

Comment: I found the solution, the argument should use the pointer. CMyClass * CM and update the value using CM->m = _T("TEST")

Comment: You could also pass by reference: `void MyFunc(CMyClass &CM)` and then use `CM.M = _T("TEST")` as in your original code.

Comment: `this`  represent the object itself, so if ou don't send that by reference it create a copy of this object. But good job if you have found the solution.